Comparing performance of probabilistic regression models - how to adapt Brier score?
Suppose I have two predictions models, Model 1 and Model 2. I have a dataset containing observations, features and actual outcomes. For each observation, the “outcomes” (i.e. predictions) that the models predicts are:

A vector of probabilities for three classes (think something like Win / Draw / Lose)
Another numerical vector of two elements  (think something like expected goals for each of the two teams playing against each other)

Now I know the specifications of Model 1 (its specific type of regression (i.e. glm), the number of features it takes, everything else). For Model 2 I only have the outcomes it produced when applied to the given dataset. There is no information on its type (one could assume it's a type of regression), the features of the dataset it uses as predictors, etc.
I wish to compare the performance of the two models only in the following ways:
a)  with respect to a certain subset of the number of elements for the probability vector (for instance, only compare performance in predicting Draws, rather than performance for Win / Draw / Lose)
b)  and with respect to some function (possibly aggregated) of the vector in 2) – for instance the performance in predicting total home goals scored for each team summed over all the observations
How can I do this for a) and b)? I could implement some sort of Brier score for a) but it seems that the Brier score definition needs to be adapted somehow since I am not interested in all 3 classes for 1) but a smaller number of them? As for b), what would be the best approach to take?
Finally, if I wanted to compare the total overall performance of the models, how could I combine a) and b) into some sort of a single "measure" of performance?

Welcome to Cross Validated! When you say you want to compare these two models, do you mean checking for self-consistency, such as predicting a draw when the final score is predicted to be 2-2?

Hi, I apologise - I had a look and edited the statement of 2), and thus b) .  Statement 2) rather than a vector of scores, should be a vector of some other quantity that the model estimates (like average expected goals). And for b) I am looking at some predicted accuracy of a quantity that is a function of a vector of 2), like total goals scored for each side. So I really want to compare accuracy of predictions of the models   @Dave
